# Slow wifi in Ubuntu 18.04 with Realtek RTL8723DE device

Tags: networking, drivers, 18.04, wireless, realtek-wireless

I am facing an issue in my HP laptop which is running Ubantu 18.04.3 when I connect with my cellphone hotspot it is running fine but in case of router it is not even connecting.
I have tried alot of troubleshoot for last 2 days but alas!.

FYR

```
sudo iwconfig 

lo1      IEEE 802.11  ESSID:"xxxxxx"  
          Mode:Managed  Frequency:2.417 GHz  Access Point: xxxxxxxxxx  
          Bit Rate=72.2 Mb/s   Tx-Power=20 dBm   
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr=2347 B   Fragment thr:off
          Encryption key:off
          Power Management:off
          Link Quality=45/70  Signal level=-65 dBm  
          Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
          Tx excessive retries:0  Invalid misc:650   Missed beacon:0
```

This info I got when I have connected with my cellphone hotspot.

Thanks in advance.

result of below given command

lspci -knn | grep Net -A3

```
libkmod: ERROR ../libkmod/libkmod-config.c:656 kmod_config_parse: /etc/modprobe.d/rtl8723be.conf line 1: ignoring bad line starting with '“options'
03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. Device [10ec:d723]
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device [103c:8319]
    Kernel driver in use: rtl8723de
    Kernel modules: rtl8723de
```

Comment: Is it slow or " not even connecting"?

Comment: it is connecting with phone hotspot but not with router wifi.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have the "low signal" problem with one antenna Realtek devices.

Also it seems that you tried to fix it, but using a wrong fix. You have some crap in `/etc/modprobe.d/rtl8723be.conf`.

So run in a terminal:

```
sudo rm /etc/modprobe.d/rtl8723be.conf
sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/rtl8723de.conf <<< "options rtl8723de ant_sel=1"
```

and reboot.

Be careful and don't make typos. It is better to copy and paste the commands. You were using wrong quotes in a previous command.

`“` is not the same as `"`.

Comment: Thanks a lot dear. My problem is solved by the same command as suggested by you instead I used ant_sel=2 . Actually I had used same troubleshoot earliar also but with typo as you mentioned earliar. Big thanks again :-)

Comment: That was not same. You used `rtl8732be` instead of `rtl8723de`.